# Keil ARMCC int64 comparison for Cortex M3

Tags: c, assembly, arm, compiler-optimization, keil

I noticed that armcc generates this kind of code to compare two int64 values:

```
0x080001B0 EA840006 EOR  r0,r4,r6
0x080001B4 EA850107 EOR  r1,r5,r7
0x080001B8 4308     ORRS r0,r0,r1
0x080001BA D101     BNE  0x080001C0
```

Which can be roughly translated as:

```
r0 = lower_word_1 ^ lower_word_2
r1 = higher_word_1 ^ higher_word_2
r0 = r1 | r0
jump if r0 is not zero
```

and something like this, when comparing int64 (int r0,r1) with integral constant (i.e. int, in r3)

```
0x08000674 4058  EORS  r0,r0,r3
0x08000676 4308  ORRS  r0,r0,r1
0x08000678 D116  BNE   0x080006A8
```

with the same idea, just skipping comparing higher words altogether since it just needs to be zero.

but I'm interested - why is it so complicated?

Both cases can be done very straight-forward by comparing lower and higher words and making BNE after both:

for two int64, assuming the same registers

```
CMP lower words
BNE
CMP higher words
BNE
```

and for int64 with integral constant:

```
CMP lower words
BNE
CBNZ if higher word is non-zero
```

This will take the same number of instructions, each may (or may not, depending on the registers used) be  2 bytes in length.

[arm-none-eabi-gcc does something different](https://godbolt.org/z/anEhvf) but no playing around with EORS either

So why armcc does this? I can't see any real benefit; both version require the same number of commands (each of which my be wide or short, so no real profit there).

The only slight benefit I can see is that less branching which my be *somewhat* beneficial for a flash prefetch buffer. But since there is no cache or branch prediction, I'm not really buying it.

So my reasoning is that this pattern is simply legacy, from ARM7 Architecture where no CBZ/CBNZ existed and mixing ARM and Thumb instructions was not very easy.
Am I missing something?

P.S. Armcc does this on every optimization level so I presume it is some kind of 'hard-coded' piece

**UPD:** Sure, there is an execution pipeline that will be flushed with every branch taken, however every solution requires at least one conditional branch that will or will not be taken (depending on integers that are compared), so pipeline will be flushed *anyway* with equal probability.
So I can't really see a point in minimizing conditional branches.

Moreover, if lower and higher words would be compared explicitly and integers are not equal, branch will be taken sooner.

Avoiding branch instruction completely is possible with IT-block but on Cortex-M3 it can be only up to 4 instructions long so I'm gonna ignore this for generality.

Comment: I wasn't immediately able to find instruction timings for the Cortex M3, but on the vast majority of CPUs in the world, ALU instructions are faster than conditional branches, with or without cache or branch prediction.  And processors without branch prediction tend to find it pretty expensive to *take* a branch.

Comment: That is a legit reason, however according to this - https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/h/programmers-model/instruction-set-summary/cortex-m3-instructions - "Conditional branch completes in a single cycle if the branch is not taken.", so no, not that simple :) Please note that in any case there _will_ be at least one conditional branch that may or may not be taken.

Comment: cmp / it / cmpeq / bne should work, and use 16-bit instructions (the predicated cmp needing an IT).  It also doesn't need any tmp regs, only flags.  Surprised your compiler doesn't use that.  Update: I checked and that *is* what GCC does: https://godbolt.org/z/4a8e1M so probably Keil's code-gen is a missed-optimization.  Unless someone can come up with a reason why that larger code would be faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes you might find accepted answer interesting; however I can see a point in your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out the difference is branching vs not branching.  If you can avoid branching you want to avoid branching.

While the ARM documentation may be interesting, as with an x86 and a full sized ARM and many other places the system plays as of a role here.  High performance cores like ones from ARM are sensitive to the system implementation.  These cortex-m cores are used in microcontrollers which are quite cost sensitive, so while they blow away a PIC or AVR or msp430 for mips to mhz and mips per dollar they are still cost sensitive.  With newer technology or perhaps higher cost, you are starting to see flashes that are at the speed of the processor for the full range (do not have to add wait states at various places across the range of valid clock speeds), but for a long time you saw the flash at half the speed of the core at the slowest core speeds.  And then getting worse as you choose higher core speeds.  But sram often matching the core. Either way flash is a major portion of the cost of the part and how much and how fast it is to some extent drives part price.

Depending on the core (anything from ARM) the fetch size and as a result alignment varies and as a result benchmarks can be skewed/manipulated based on alignment of a loop style test and how many fetches are needed (trivial to demonstrate with many cortex-ms).  The cortex-ms are generally either a halfword or full word fetch and some are compile time options for the chip vendor (so you might have two chips with the same core but the performance varies).  And this can be demonstrated too...just not here...unless pushed, I have done this demo too many times at this site now.  But we can manage that here in this test.

I do not have a cortex-m3 handy I would have to dig one out and wire it up if need be, should not need to though have a cortex-m4 handy which is also an armv7-m.  A NUCLEO-F411RE

Test fixture

```
.thumb_func
.globl HOP
HOP:
    bx r2

.balign 0x20

.thumb_func
.globl TEST0
TEST0:
    push {r4,r5}

    mov r4,#0
    mov r5,#0

    ldr r2,[r0]
t0:
    cmp r4,r5
    beq skip
skip:   
    subs r1,r1,#1
    bne t0
    
    ldr r3,[r0]
    subs r0,r2,r3

    pop {r4,r5}
    bx lr
```

The systick timer generally works just fine for these kinds of tests, no need to mess with the debuggers timer it often just shows the same thing with more work. More than enough here.

Called like this with the result printed out in hex

```
hexstring(TEST0(STK_CVR,0x10000));
hexstring(TEST0(STK_CVR,0x10000));
```

copy the flash code to ram and execute there

```
hexstring(HOP(STK_CVR,0x10000,0x20000001));
hexstring(HOP(STK_CVR,0x10000,0x20000001));
```

Now the stm32's have this cache thing in front of the flash which affects loop based benchmarks like these as well as other benchmarks against these parts, sometimes you cannot get past that and you end up with a bogus benchmark. But not in this case.

To demonstrate fetch effects you want a system delay in fetching, if the fetches are too fast you might not see the fetch effects.

```
0800002c <t0>:
 800002c:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 800002e:   d1ff        bne.n   8000030 <skip>

08000030 <skip>:

00050001 <-- flash time
00050001 <-- flash time
00060004 <-- sram time
00060004 <-- sram time

0800002c <t0>:
 800002c:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 800002e:   d0ff        beq.n   8000030 <skip>

08000030 <skip>:

00060001
00060001
00080000
00080000

0800002c <t0>:
 800002c:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 800002e:   bf00        nop

08000030 <skip>:

00050001
00050001
00060000
00060000
```

So we can see that if the branch is not taken it is the same as a nop.  As far as this loop based test goes.  So perhaps there is a branch predictor (often a small cache that remembers the last N number of branches and their destinations and can start prefetch a clock or two early).  I did not dig into it yet, did not really need to as we can already see that there is a performance cost due to a branch that has to be taken (making your suggested code not equal despite the same number of instructions, this is the same number of instructions but not equal performance).

So the quickest way to remove the loop and avoid the stm32 cache thing is to do something like this in ram

```
push {r4,r5}

mov r4,#0
mov r5,#0
cmp r4,r5

ldr r2,[r0]

instruction under test repeated many times

ldr r3,[r0]
subs r0,r2,r3

pop {r4,r5}
bx lr
```

with the instruction under test being a bne to the next, a beq to the next or a nop

```
// 800002e: d1ff        bne.n   8000030 <skip>
00002001
// 800002e: d0ff        beq.n   8000030 <skip>
00004000
// 800002e: bf00        nop
00001001
```

I did not have room for 0x10000 instructions so I used 0x1000, and we can see that there is a hit for both branch types with the one that does branch being more costly.

Note that the loop based benchmark did not show this difference, have to be careful doing benchmarks or judging results.  Even the ones I have shown here.

I could spend more time tweaking core settings or system settings, but based on experience I think this has already demonstrated the desire not to have a cmp, bne, cbnz replace eor, orr, bne.  Now to be fair, your other one where it is a eor.w (thumb2 extensions) that burns more clocks than thumb2 instructions so there is another thing to consider (I measured it as well).

Remember for these high performance cores you need to be very sensitive to fetching and fetch alignment, very easy to make a bad benchmark.  Not that an x86 is not high performance, but to make the inefficient core run smoother there is a ton of stuff around it to try to keep the core fed, similar to running a semi-truck vs a sports car, the truck can be efficient once up to speed on the highway but city driving, not so much even keeping to the speed limit a Yugo will get across town faster than the semi truck (if it does not break down).  Fetch effects, unaligned transfers, etc are difficult to see in an x86, but an ARM somewhat easy, so to get the best performance you want to avoid the easy cycle eaters.

### Edit

Note that I jumped to conclusions too early about what GCC produces.  Had to work more on trying to craft an equivalent comparison.  I started with

```
unsigned long long fun2 ( unsigned long long a)
{
    if(a==0) return(1);
    return(0);
}
unsigned long long fun3 ( unsigned long long a)
{
    if(a!=0) return(1);
    return(0);
}
00000028 <fun2>:
  28:   460b        mov r3, r1
  2a:   2100        movs    r1, #0
  2c:   4303        orrs    r3, r0
  2e:   bf0c        ite eq
  30:   2001        moveq   r0, #1
  32:   4608        movne   r0, r1
  34:   4770        bx  lr
  36:   bf00        nop

00000038 <fun3>:
  38:   460b        mov r3, r1
  3a:   2100        movs    r1, #0
  3c:   4303        orrs    r3, r0
  3e:   bf14        ite ne
  40:   2001        movne   r0, #1
  42:   4608        moveq   r0, r1
  44:   4770        bx  lr
  46:   bf00        nop
```

Which used an it instruction which is a natural solution here since the if-then-else cases can be a single instruction.  Interesting that they chose to use r1 instead of the immediate #0 I wonder if that is a generic optimization, due to complexity with immediates on a fixed length instruction set or perhaps immediates take less space on some architectures.  Who knows.

```
 800002e:   bf0c        ite eq
 8000030:   bf00        nopeq
 8000032:   bf00        nopne
00003002 
00003002 

 800002e:   bf14        ite ne
 8000030:   bf00        nopne
 8000032:   bf00        nopeq
00003002 
00003002
```

Using sram 0x1000 sets of three instructions linearly, so 0x3002 means 1 clock per instruction on average.

Putting a mov in the it block doesn't change performance

```
ite eq
moveq   r0, #1
movne   r0, r1
```

It is still one clock per.

```
void more_fun ( unsigned int );
unsigned long long fun4 ( unsigned long long a)
{
    for(;a!=0;a--)
    {
        more_fun(5);
    }
    return(0);
}
  48:   b538        push    {r3, r4, r5, lr}
  4a:   ea50 0301   orrs.w  r3, r0, r1
  4e:   d00a        beq.n   66 <fun4+0x1e>
  50:   4604        mov r4, r0
  52:   460d        mov r5, r1
  54:   2005        movs    r0, #5
  56:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <more_fun>
  5a:   3c01        subs    r4, #1
  5c:   f165 0500   sbc.w   r5, r5, #0
  60:   ea54 0305   orrs.w  r3, r4, r5
  64:   d1f6        bne.n   54 <fun4+0xc>
  66:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  68:   2100        movs    r1, #0
  6a:   bd38        pop {r3, r4, r5, pc}
```

This is basically the compare with zero

```
  60:   ea54 0305   orrs.w  r3, r4, r5
  64:   d1f6        bne.n   54 <fun4+0xc>
```

Against another

```
void more_fun ( unsigned int );
unsigned long long fun4 ( unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b)
{
    for(;a!=b;a--)
    {
        more_fun(5);
    }
    return(0);
}

00000048 <fun4>:
  48:   4299        cmp r1, r3
  4a:   bf08        it  eq
  4c:   4290        cmpeq   r0, r2
  4e:   d011        beq.n   74 <fun4+0x2c>
  50:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
  52:   4604        mov r4, r0
  54:   460d        mov r5, r1
  56:   4617        mov r7, r2
  58:   461e        mov r6, r3
  5a:   2005        movs    r0, #5
  5c:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <more_fun>
  60:   3c01        subs    r4, #1
  62:   f165 0500   sbc.w   r5, r5, #0
  66:   42ae        cmp r6, r5
  68:   bf08        it  eq
  6a:   42a7        cmpeq   r7, r4
  6c:   d1f5        bne.n   5a <fun4+0x12>
  6e:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  70:   2100        movs    r1, #0
  72:   bdf8        pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
  74:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  76:   2100        movs    r1, #0
  78:   4770        bx  lr
  7a:   bf00        nop
```

And they choose to use an it block here.

```
  66:   42ae        cmp r6, r5
  68:   bf08        it  eq
  6a:   42a7        cmpeq   r7, r4
  6c:   d1f5        bne.n   5a <fun4+0x12>
```

It is on par with this for number of instructions.

```
0x080001B0 EA840006 EOR  r0,r4,r6
0x080001B4 EA850107 EOR  r1,r5,r7
0x080001B8 4308     ORRS r0,r0,r1
0x080001BA D101     BNE  0x080001C0
```

But those thumb2 instructions are going to execute longer.  So overall I think GCC appears to have made a better sequence, but of course you want to check apples to apples start with the same C code and see what each produced.  The gcc one reads easier than the eor/orr stuff, can think less about what it is doing.

```
 8000040:   406c        eors    r4, r5
00001002
 8000042:   ea94 0305   eors.w  r3, r4, r5
00002001
```

0x1000 instructions one is two halfwords (thumb2) one is one halfword (thumb).  Takes two clocks not really surprised.

```
0x080001B0 EA840006 EOR  r0,r4,r6
0x080001B4 EA850107 EOR  r1,r5,r7
0x080001B8 4308     ORRS r0,r0,r1
0x080001BA D101     BNE  0x080001C0
```

I see six clocks there before adding any other penalties, not four (on this cortex-m4).

Note I made the eors.w aligned and unaligned and it did not change the performance.  Still two clocks.

Comment: So basically you are saying that despite what docs say, branch not taken takes more cycles than a nop instruction (or a bit manipulation like xor/or) and therefore avoiding branches still makes sense (please correct me if I'm wrong)?

Comment: Also i'm really impressed with your benchmarking skills, thank you very much for that one!

Comment: Fair enough. It actually makes sense that Keil uses some internal knowledge about architecture while gcc doesn't. My own explanation was "historical" but your data fits better :) Thanks again!

Comment: It was a case of how I crafted the C code and left it at the first experiment, where further experiments generated competing solutions with Keils compiler and I would argue a better solution, but really needs to be apples to apples start with the same C code, I dont have the Keil tools and no longer have access to ARM's tools, so all I can do is compare clang and gcc (unless godbolt has them).

Comment: It is not a case of Keil now being owned by arm and maybe having their legacy tools replaced knows more about the cores, it is a case of who happened to have someone sit down and look for this optimization and implement it.  I have seen arms tools get beat by other non-arm (, non-gnu) tools.  What matters in all cases is how good does it do with "your" code not a benchmark but your application, that is the real ruler to measure these things by.

Comment: Take my benchmarks with a grain of salt as you would with any benchmark.  Repeat these kinds of things yourself on your own hardware.  Just understand that one result is not the end of the story, understand the result and the test and where you might have missed something.

Comment: Sure. I'm aware that nobody except someone from ARM will tell me 100% truth about this; but your reasoning looks sound to me.

Comment: www.jagregory.com/abrash-zen-of-asm/ and a pdf from github.com/jagregory/abrash-zen-of-asm the 8088 was old when the book came out and is obviously older now, if that is all anyone sees in this book they are missing out.   I have used what I learned here almost daily for the last so many decades.  I have beat up processors and other logic as well as made them perform as a result of this book and lots of practice.  But as he also points out, just try stuff, crazy stuff, as sometimes you find something you didnt expect.  Also dont expect to always be able to explain what you see in the results.

Comment: With experience and luck you can also get a job with a company that makes chips and has the source code to one or more cores and might go so far as to have access to that code and as simulation tool to see the processor executing, manipulating the code and see how the processor reacts.  There are other ways to gain access, right place, right time, right potential as a customer, right signature on the right documentation.

Comment: https://www.arm.com/resources/designstart/designstart-fpga

Answer (score 4):

The efficiency of the generated code is not counted in the number of the machine code instructions. You need to know the internals of the target machine as well (not only the clock/instruction) but also how the fetch/decode/execute process works.

Every branch instruction in the Cortex M3 devices flushes the pipeline. Pipeline has to be fed again. If you run from FLASH memory (it is slow) wait states will also significantly slow this process. The compiler tries to avoid branches as much as it is possible.

It can be done your way using other instructions:

```
int foo(int64_t x, int64_t y)
{
    return x == y;
}

        cmp     r1, r3
        itte    eq
        cmpeq   r0, r2
        moveq   r0, #1
        movne   r0, #0
        bx      lr
```

Trust your compiler. People who write them know their trade :). Before you learn more about the ARM Cortex you cant judge the compiler this simple way as you do now.

The code from your example is very well optimized and simple. Keil does a very good job.

Comment: Right, I forgot about instruction pipeline. However, does it _really_ affect execution speed that much? If I remember correctly, it is just 3 instructions or smthn close? And anyway - if there is a comparison - there will be a branch. If it is not taken, it doesn't flush the pipeline - and if it is taken, it will. What's the difference if it will be the second BNE of the two or the only one?

Comment: You have no branches in the good code. That is the rule of thumb - try do not branch at all.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I'm not looking for a hand-optimizing something specific, where this is possible, I'm interested in compilers reasoning in a general case of something like `if( a == b ) {....}`

Comment: @Amomum the reason is: make it efficient and simple. Two XORs and one OR is simple and very efficient. What other reason do you want?  Now your question is: why compilers do not optimize it the not optimized way?

Comment: 3 cycles of the pipeline refill if you your flash has 7 wait states can be op to 28 clocks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. EOR+EOR+ORR+BNE - 4 instructions, one possible branch. CMP+BNE+CMP+BNE - 4 instructions, two possible branches but with the same probability of being taken. If numbers are equal, no branching will occur in both cases; if they are not - there will be a branch.

Comment: you are forgetting that brach is not always needed. In your solution always. https://godbolt.org/z/To51az

Comment: Sure but it is also always needed in Keils solution! And I'm asking about Keils reasoning. Avoiding a branch is great but it's only possible for very small amount of code inside if/else, only up to 4 instructions can be inside IT block.

Comment: @Amomum just benchmark it yourself you are assuming/relying on the core being fed with no delays which is rare many flashes run at half the cpu rate so the core stalls a lot anyway just fetching.  Some have cache schemes and prefetchers that can compensate a little if in a loop or if your alignment is just right relative to the prefetch algnment and size, note that some cortex-ms can be compiled to fetch a halfword at a time and some a word.

Comment: @old_timer I suppose that a lot of those things are also vendor-related, compiler shouldn't be aware of them.. I think? Correctly benchmarking such a small piece can be tricky though. I prefer to postpone it :)

Comment: Nope, somewhat trivial, composing my answer now.  You can sometimes see the differences even with different vendor implementations.  The compiler is choosing the path known to be better performance independent of the implementation.  While true there are times that the compiler chooses a path that might be better performance (using a multiply instead of a divide for say divide by 10 for cores that have both), in this case it is...